# Spring Security with multi-factor authentication

Tags: spring-security

Is there a way to configure Spring Security for supporting multi-factor authentication?

I want to first ask the user name and the password from the user and then ask security answer of the security question.

Thanks
Rosh

Answer (score 0):

Could you be clearer about whether or not you need the security question to be on a second page?

If having the security question on the same page as the username and password would work for your situation, there are several ways to do this. One of the easiest is to extend the [`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html) to support a second field and then to modify your [`UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html#loadUserByUsername%28java.lang.String%29) method to extract the second field.

[Here is an article](http://blog.awnry.com/post/16183749439/two-factor-authentication-and-spring-security-3) that outlines the steps for doing so.